# running exe in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, executable

I have built a simple console application in c++ vs2010 that just displays one line of text. Is it possible to run this executable from the Release folder in Linux? 
Say I put the Release folder on a thumb drive, open it on a linux machine?

I was under the impression that console application written in c++ could run in both windows in linux? how mislead am I?

Comment: No, the binaries are not compatible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a) You need to run the executable with wine and emulate a windows environment
- **OR** -
b) You need to compile your code for your Linux distribution.

Comment: To be clear -- this is either A or B, as opposed to needing both.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of that. Is there any way to compile for linux using vs?

Comment: @user1601045 Yes, if I remember correctly, but it's not simple. VS triggers MSBuild, which can be told to run GCC/G++ instead of CL. However, you have to muck around deep in the build process; I don't know of any wizards or simple support, and the projects VS spits out are difficult to adapt. You may look into something like CMake to generate both VS projects and nix-compatible make files.

Comment: alright, thanks for the help.. I am just going to rebuild the app in Linux.